# Magento 2: How to get Browser Session ID in custom module

Tags: session, magento2.3.3, browser

I need to get `Browser Session ID` in my custom module.

Does any have idea how to get `Browser Session Id` in custom module.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please explain more about why you want browser session id?

Comment: I need Browser Session Id to send the data to third party via rest API.